# How to divide each face of a cube to small sub-divisions using PyOpengl?

Tags: python, opengl, cube, pyopengl

I am trying to make a game where each face of cube has different numbers displayed in small sections. For eg:- Face 1 of the cube can have Numbers from 1 to 25, so I need 5 * 5 sections for this face, Face 2 can have numbers from 26 to 50, so I need 5 * 5 sections on this face etc. I have made a simple cube using PyOpengGl. But I haven't seen any documentation regarding the sub-division of a cube/rectangle etc. Is it possible to make such small divisions for a cube and display it with numbers ?

Comment: Just define your own subdivided cube, i.e. construct vertices out of (0,0,0), (1/divisions,0,0), etc. Or, use Blender to make a subdivided cube and import it.

Comment: As per your comment, I used Blender to create the cube and sub divide it. But I do not understand how can I proceed after this ? Blender made it easy to design the GUI but for the logical section, Is there a method to parse the output file of Blender and import it to continue making changes in python ?

Comment: Yes, you can find many 3D file parsers online like assimp. Or you can write your own obj file parser (easier than you think!). This may sound like a lot of work, but you'll end up needing to make meshes with external software rather than hardcoded values sooner or later.